# Split first name and last name by coma in long string full name?

Tags: php, string, split

I have a column to store the authors of acticles. The number of author is depend on each article (from 1 to 20 authors or more). An example with 4 authors:

```
$author = "Jame Bond; John Thomas Dier; Calos Teves; Ronaldo Rondigez";
```

How to replace the first space in single full name by (,) and (;) by and like this string:

```
$author = "Jame, Bond and John, Thomas Dier and Calos, Teves and Ronaldo, Rondigez";
```

I used this code to replace (;) into AND

```
$author = str_replace(";"," and",$author);
```

Thanks,

Comment: What if a Name like your `Nguyen Hoang Bach` come? Do you need to split it as `Nguyen, Hoang Bach`? `;` to `and` can be replaced because we have a index value to replace, in case of space how can we do that as you expected? surly we can but it might not be right as in your name.

Comment: Are you sure that’s actually the output you want? Because you rather seem to have first name and last name backwards here, at least by general English language convention - which is to list people that are named _Firstname Lastname_ as _Lastname Comma Firstname_. And making “John Thomas Dier” into “John, Thomas Dier” also doesn’t seem to make much sense, “John Thomas” are likely to be the first and second name here, and only “Dier” the last name. (Although not necessarily, which means doing a naive split-at-first-space is probably not going to to a proper job here to begin with.)

Comment: okay, if you want to export to bibtex file, the author format is first, last name, so we can separate the authors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$author = "Jame Bond; John Thomas Dier; Calos Teves; Ronaldo Rondigez";
$tempArr=explode(";",$author);
foreach($tempArr as $value)
{
   $temp[]= preg_replace('/ /', ',', trim($value), 1);
} 
echo $author = implode(" and ",$temp);
```